# onclick in window.onload in javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider the snippet:

```
    <head>      
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                function callMe(){
                    alert("Inside the function");
                    this.value = "New Value";                   
                }
                document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
            }
        </script>       
    </head>
    <body>          
        <input type="submit" id="thisCall" />   
    </body>
```

The above works fine as expected and the button text is changed from Submit to New Value.

But why doesn't the below snippet works if I do a slight modification?

```
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
                function callMe(){
                    alert("Inside the function");
                    this.value = "New Value";                   
                }
                //document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>          
        <input type="submit" id="thisCall" onclick="callMe();"/>        
    </body>
```

and I don't understand why

> Uncaught ReferenceError: callMe is not defined

is the o/p at the console?

Comment: Because callMe is only known inside the scope of the onload function declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function declaration creates a variable pointing to the function *in the current scope*.

In JavaScript, each function creates a new scope.

You are creating `callMe` inside the scope of the anonymous function you assign to `onload`. It is not a global.

The `onclick` event handler is not in the scope of the aforementioned anonymous function, so the variable is not accessible.

Comment: That means I need to move the function callMe() out of the onload function in the second case.

Comment: Better to avoid the second case altogether and not use `onclick` attributes. Globals are best avoided. `with` is best avoided (and `onclick` attributes implement `width` internally). Mixing your JS and HTML is best avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that the `callMe()` function declaration is inside the onload scope so it's local to it and it's only visible inside this scope.

You have to put it outside so it will be a global function and can be visible outside and accessible from outside:

```
function callMe(){
     alert("Inside the function");
     this.value = "New Value";                   
}


window.onload = function(){
      callMe();  
      document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
}
```

**EDIT:**

And this code :

```
document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe;
```

Is working because it's written inside the onload function scope, where the function `callMe` is defined.

And it will not work if you use it with the `onclick` attribute, because like said `callMe()`isn't recognized in the global scope and that's the reason why you got `callMe is not defined` there.

Comment: I see that the button text is changed only when I use document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe; since in case of just callMe(), this refers to the instance of the callMe function, and I haven't creted any instance of callMe function.

Comment: Yes that's because the code `document.getElementById("thisCall").onclick = callMe` is in the onload scope, where the function callMe is defined.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to scope. Your function only exists within the scope of the anonymous function assigned to the window.onload method. That anonymous method is aware of the method since it's defined in its scope and can invoke it but nothing outside of that scope can.

Does that make sense?